# Loading data from network per item in RecyclerView

Tags: android, rest, android-recyclerview, request, adapter

From server (API REST), I can obtain a list of item (products) with some info of each one. I map that list in a RecyclerView with an Adapter. I show a loading view until I receive that list.

However, I have to show more info per item in each row, but I can only get that info with another HTTP request (per item), sending the ID of that product. Therefore, I want to fill the UI of each row with that info asynchronously (when the row is showing).

How is the better way of achieve that? I think this is the same problematic as asynchronous image loading, so I should do something as libraries such as Picasso or Universal Image Loading. Isn't it?

Do you know any library in order to help me with that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could use an AsyncTaskLoader for each RecyclerView entry which starts up if the row is showing.

Comment: Yes! Anyway, I should manage the the reuse of views with de ViewHolder: maybe, when the service responds, the view is reused and is associated with another item.

Comment: If you have a static view it will be easy to reuse. if you have a "on click visible" view it has to be rendered in any case. 
If you do this operation often maybe you should think about a holding data structure which is filled by null at beginning (so a click would issue a Asynctask) and if you already downloaded the corresponding item it is filled (a click would issue a loading from object). 
Or if it is not to big (no images or videos) download the additional information completly at the beginning, it sounds like overhead, but sometimes it make things easier and more efficient than before.

Comment: did you find a lib or a good example on this?

Comment: do you have any solution for this problem? Any recommendation?

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this by using RxJava library. For example, in your `onBindViewHolder` method you would possibly do something like this:

```
Observable.fromCallable {
    loadDataAsync(position, <other arguments you need>)
}.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
 .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
 .subscribe { loadedData ->
     holder.setAdditionalData(loadedData)
 }
```

Of course you must keep track on each subscription and unsubscribe after the item has been recycled in order to prevent memory leaks.

Anyway your should probably revise your API design and make the server send all data in one request/response cycle rather than making a tons of small HTTP requests for each item. In this case your problem just disappears.

Comment: Thanks! Maybe it's OK.But I think it needs a lot of more management, such as control the number of active network connections (with a ThreadPoolExecutor), or check if a item's data has already been request (and cache it). So it's mandatory to create a manager; and maybe RxJava doesn't provide any help.